Creating a web worker in a Stackblitz Lit Element Project?
I'm trying to create a web worker in a Lit Element Stackblitz Project.
This is the worker (worker.js):
onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
  postMessage(e.data);
};

And this is the code that creates it ( In my-element.ts` ):
  constructor() {
    super();
    const worker: Worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    console.log(worker);
    worker.postMessage('hello');
    worker.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(`The worker posted back ${e.data}`);
    };
  }

And the demo, when viewed with developer tooling, does not log any messages inside or from the worker, however it does log:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at worker.js:1:1)

And I'm trying to figure out whether this is a Stackblitz bug and if there are any ways of getting around it?
Thoughts?

You have 2 ways.
1. Use absolute path
Since WebContainer is a file system emulated environment so its sw cannot find your worker context exactly you can
 constructor() {
    super();
    const worker: Worker = new Worker('/src/worker.js');
    console.log(worker);
    worker.postMessage('hello');
    worker.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(`The worker posted back ${e.data}`);
    };
  }

2. Use ?worker with syntax Vite
Since you are using vite, there is an easier way which is to use vite's syntax
import Worker from "./worker?worker"

 constructor() {
    super();
    const worker: Worker = new Worker();
    console.log(worker);
    worker.postMessage('hello');
    worker.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(`The worker posted back ${e.data}`);
    };
  }

